# can we create unit tests for custom widgets in a django app?

Tags: django, unit-testing, widget

I'm new with unit testing in django, I have referred to the django [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/testing/) to write unit tests for views, forms and models. But a question came to my mind about widgets if they could be also tested, since unit tests are made to test every single unit in the project.

For example I have a widget that let me write multiple emails in one inputText using a plugin and the widget as follow is made to change `'` to `"` so that the plugin can work.

```
class MultiEmailWidget(Input):
def value_from_datadict(self, data, files, name):
    if name in data:
        if data[name]:
            return data[name].replace(']' ,'').replace('[','').replace('"' ,'').replace(',' , '\n')
    return None
def render_value(self , value):
    """
    change ' to " because multiple_email.js do split with "
    """

    if value:
        return str(value).replace("'",'"')
    return value

def render(self, name, value, attrs=None):
    value = self.render_value(value)
    return super(MultiEmailWidget, self).render(name, value, attrs)
```

Is this widget testable ? 
Or do somebody have some useful links about testing widgets in django ? (if this is testable ofcourse)

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Yes, widgets can be tested. You can find tests for Django's built-in widgets  for reference here: https://github.com/django/django/tree/master/tests/forms_tests/widget_tests

Comment: If this is some logic that involves both some javascript in the front end and the django server side handling, it would make sense to test it in a end-to-end test using Selenium.